# Select nodes that share some of the same tags, and sort by tags in common count

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have nodes that can have many tags.
I'm able to display nodes that share some of the tags.

```
        $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');

        if ($nodeId != null) {
            $query->condition('nid', $nodeId, '<>');
        }
        $query->condition('field_tags', $tagsIds, 'IN');
        $query->condition('status', 1);
```

That works. But now I'd like to sort them by relevance. In other words, the ones that have the most tags in common should come first.

Any idea how I can achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: I wrote an article about how to do that in Views, so it may help you if you create the Views it gives you the SQL you can use or start with: https://prkos.hr/Sort-related-content-Relevance-Drupal-8